# Saving Payment Methods with PayPal Checkout

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway

Is it possible to attach payment methods to customers when PayPal uses the card checkout? I'm asking this because it seems like in order to have the PayPal buttons on the checkout, trying to use PayPal's hosted payment fields seems to not support having external customers with saved cards.

My goal is to have it so I can have the PayPal button along with the PayPal hosted fields for cards, and then if a user does checkout with the hosted fields, it will save their card somehow. This sort of functionality doesn't really seem to be supported by PayPal's API according to the docs unless I'm missing something.

I'm just trying to figure out a way if you can use previous cards in paypal's hosted checkout if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Saving payment methods requires a feature variously called reference transactions or vaulting (the v2 vault API, *not* v1). The feature is not enable by default. The business owner should contact PayPal's general business support (not technical support) or an account manager to inquire about the reference transactions feature and explain the business need.

If approved for the feature, PayPal can then guide you on which API to integrate.